# Flutter local notification not work in latest version

Tags: flutter, localnotification

I am trying to implement local notification which works perfect before I upgrade my app version as below:

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  showNotification() async {
   var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel name');
    var iOS = DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var platform = NotificationDetails(android: android, iOS: iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'Hello user,',
        "Don't miss out on the exciting deals for the day.", RepeatInterval.everyMinute, platform);
   
  }
```

But since I changed to `flutter_local_notifications: ^10.0.0` then I couldn't get any notification again.Though I got an error message `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'periodicallyShow' was called on null.` and `Tried calling: periodicallyShow(0, "Hello Hobber,", "Don't miss out on the exciting deals for the day.", Instance of 'RepeatInterval', Instance of 'NotificationDetails')` Can someone help?

Comment: Well it seems that `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` is not created so you are calling method `periodicallyShow()` on null value.
You should read the changelog [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog) for the appropriate version. If your error is really caused by the upgrade of this plugin, you might find what breaking changes they introduced.

Comment: I have it declared already but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin object like this:

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin()